# EF Core 3.1 - Disconnected Graph - Navigation Property - Entity Already Tracked Exception - Way Forward

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have the following entity graph:

Customer -> Has Multiple Addresses -> Each Address has a Country navigation property

I have used scaffolding to reverse-engineer the classes, hence there are no issues with the configurations.

```
public class Customers {
   public Customers() {
      Addresses = new List<Addresses>();
   }

   public int CustomerId {
      get; set;
   }

   public string FirstName {
      get; set;
   }

   public string LastName {
      get; set;
   }

   public int CustomerTypeId {
      get; set;
   }

   public CustomerTypes CustomerType {
      get; set;
   }

   public ICollection<Addresses> Addresses {
      get; set;
   }
}

public class Addresses {
   public int AddressId {
      get; set;
   }

   public int CustomerId {
      get; set;
   }

   public int AddressTypeId {
      get; set;
   }

   public string ZipPostalcode {
      get; set;
   }

   public int CountryId {
      get; set;
   }

   public AddressTypes AddressType {
      get; set;
   }

   public Countries Country {
      get; set;
   }
}

public class Countries {
   public int CountryId {
      get; set;
   }

   public string Alpha2Code {
      get; set;
   }

   public string Alpha3Code {
      get; set;
   }

   public string EnglishName {
      get; set;
   }

   public string FrenchName {
      get; set;
   }
}
```

I can have a customer with two addresses - each with different address types such as Home and Business - but in same country (say US).

Below is the simplified code that gets invoked to update the graph - just to show the flow, I first retrieve the customer graph, make changes and try to update (each action in a new DbContext):

```
public static void Update_Using_TrackGraph(DbContextOptions<PolyglotContext> contextOptions) {
   Customers customer;

   using (var context = new PolyglotContext(contextOptions)) {
      customer = context.Customers
                        .Include(x => x.CustomerType)
                        .Include(x => x.Addresses)
                              .ThenInclude(x => x.AddressType)
                        .Include(x => x.Addresses)
                              .ThenInclude(x => x.Country)
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.CustomerId == 1);
   }

   customer.EmailAddress = "new.email@avengers.com";
   foreach (var address in customer.Addresses)
      address.Line3 = "Thor Town";

   using var ctx = new PolyglotContext(contextOptions);

   ctx.ChangeTracker.Tracked += (s, e) => {
      Console.WriteLine($"{e.Entry.Entity}: {e.Entry.State}");
   };

   ctx.ChangeTracker.StateChanged += (s, e) => {
      Console.WriteLine($"{e.Entry.Entity}: {e.OldState} - {e.NewState}");
   };

   ctx.ChangeTracker
      .TrackGraph(customer, e => {
         e.Entry.State = e.Entry.IsKeySet ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;
      });

   ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I try to attach the graph, I get the following error:

```
The instance of entity type 'Countries' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'CountryId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

After doing some lookup, I understand this error is expected as of EF 3.1. There are discussions about this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20116) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19984).

Question - How do I resolve this issue? I have tried the following options and they all do work:

**Option 1** - I modified the TrackGraph behavior as follows:

```
e.Entry.State = e.Entry.Entity.GetType() == typeof(Countries) ? EntityState.Detached
                  : (e.Entry.IsKeySet ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added);
```

**Option 2** - When updating, be explicit about the entity being updated, no graph updates. This would mean updating one entity at a time

Are there any other options available? I am looking for expertise from those who have worked on similar graph update schenarios?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Option 3 - Based on an idea by Julie Lerman (@julielerman) for entities that require audit functionality, I could define a contract to identify entities that should not be tracked and then modify TrackGraph method to detach any entities that implements this interface. I believe the code would be a bit cleaner.